# Unable to loop using az network vnet subnet list from the variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have got the code below, however I am unable to loop from the `$subnets`  to get the name and use that within the code. What I am trying to do is delete all the subnets within the virtual network.

```
$rg = "xxxx"
$vnet = "dddd"
$subnets = az network vnet subnet list --resource-group $rg --vnet-name $vnet
foreach ($subnet in $subnets.name)
{
    write-host $subnet
    az network vnet subnet delete --name $subnet --resource-group $rg --vnet-name $vnet

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code to loop from the `$subnets` to get the name and use that within the code

```
$rg = "<RGName>"
$vnet = "<vnetName>"
$subnets = az network vnet subnet list --resource-group $rg --vnet-name $vnet | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($subnet in $subnets)
{
    write-host $subnet.name
    az network vnet subnet delete --name $subnet.name --resource-group $rg --vnet-name $vnet
}
```

When I ran the above code, subnets listed successfully:

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in portal where subnets deleted successfully like below:

[image]